# wordpress add own javascript file. no reaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I add to children template directory in scripts.php code:

```
<?php

function load_styles_and_scripts() {

  wp_register_script (
    'myScript',
    get_template_directory_uri().'/script.js',
    array('jquery'),
    '1.11.0',
    true
  );

  wp_enqueue_script ('myScript');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles_and_scripts');
```

my script.js file contain:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
```

[folders / paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvRkt.png)

I set my optional theme in wordpress as active one.
CSS is loading correct but javascript from script.js not - is no making any differences on site.

I fight all day with this. 
Thanks straight away ;)

[Script is loaded - firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Qjg.png)

Comment: Check errors in browser dev tools console. Wordpress usually uses jQuery.noConflict() making `$` undefined. Also check dev tools network that file is being loaded

Comment: Also, do you have jquery loaded?

Comment: no errors - script is loaded (added to <script src="...> in footer)

Comment: just because script tag is there doesn't mean path is correct and file itself has loaded. Check in netowrk tab

Comment: if I add:/// wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); /// no changes. Even this /// array('jquery'), /// should add jQuery to my script - i think..

Comment: I just find out that path is going to franz-josef directory not to franz-jozef-child.

Comment: Ok - after repair path everything is working but I cant use jQuery. Thanks for show me direction :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use jQuery with WordPress, you must use the string 'jQuery' instead of '$'. For example:

```
jQuery('#id').show();
```

If you wish to override the jQuery function and use '$', checkout this reference https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/. So for your example do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('ready!');
    alert('Hello! I am an alert box!');
});
```

Comment: Working !! Thanks a Lot ! I want to give U positive feedback but I have no 15 reputation points ;)

Comment: Thats great to hear :)